# Create an intent for alexa skill using API

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask

Does aws provide any API to create the intent for skill from the code itself dynamically.
Rather than create it from the UI console from developer.amazon.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can create skills with [Alexa Skills Kit Command Line Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html)  - (ASK-CLI) without the GUI.

Specific for creating intents you should read here:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#create-skill-subcommand

Answer (score 0):

You have the Alexa skill kit command that allow you to manage your skill without using the Alexa UI console

Check this -> https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html